# Where is the Runeguard for the Defiant faction in RIFT?

Tags: rift

Where is the Runeguard for the Defiant faction in RIFT?  The current world event requires me to find them, but doesn't exactly state where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runeguard for the Defiant faction is located in the Gardens of Meridian. Coming in from the entrance make a right at the mounts and head all the way to the far end. He is down there.[image: This best i can do for visual representation]

Answer (score 0):

TBH i'm not sure because i stopped playing Rift but probable you mean the Runeguard faction:

> The Runeguard are the dwarves that stayed behind to defend and free
> their homeland of Moonshade Highlands. While individuals may have
> feelings for the gods, or not, as a group they owe allegiance only to
> the true King of Hammerknell.
>
> Quartermaster Balint located at 6300,1600 in Moonshade Highlands

Source: [The Runeguard (Rift Faction)](http://rift.zam.com/wiki/The_Runeguard_%28Rift_Faction%29)